# Insert a static list as a new column into PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of items:

```py
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I have an existing dataframe, and I want to insert `my_list` as a new column into the existing dataframe.

Example input dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("1", "foo"), ("2", "bar"), ("3", "baz")], ["id", "value"])
df.show()
# +---+-----+
# | id|value|
# +---+-----+
# |  1|  foo|
# |  2|  bar|
# |  3|  baz|
# +---+-----+
```

Desired output:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id|value|new_column|
+---+-----+----------+
|  1|  foo| [a, b, c]|
|  2|  bar| [a, b, c]|
|  3|  baz| [a, b, c]|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a static list as a new column:

```
df = df.withColumn("new_column", F.array([F.lit(x) for x in my_list]))

df.show()
```

Which yields:

```
+---+-----+----------+
| id|value|new_column|
+---+-----+----------+
|  1|  foo| [a, b, c]|
|  2|  bar| [a, b, c]|
|  3|  baz| [a, b, c]|
+---+-----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

**`map`** can be used too:

```py
df = df.withColumn("new_column", F.array(*map(F.lit, my_list)))

df.show()
# +---+-----+----------+
# | id|value|new_column|
# +---+-----+----------+
# |  1|  foo| [a, b, c]|
# |  2|  bar| [a, b, c]|
# |  3|  baz| [a, b, c]|
# +---+-----+----------+
```